# I need to get the nt-user using PHP (Single Sign On / seamless authentication)

Tags: php, single-sign-on, ntlm

I am struggling with Single Sign On. I just need to know who is using my Intranet page.

So I thought I use Single Sign On to get the username (ntuser).

But I have some problems with it. 
I can't find a simple way to get the username with PHP...

My Apache (httpd) is running on a Red Hat Enterprice Linux machine.
I've installed to mod_auth_ntlm and the mod_auth_ntlm_winbind.

I am not quite sure if I configured it the right way... and I haven't a php sample to test it.

May someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

check this to articles : 
https://drupal.org/node/1428254
http://bloke.org/linux/ntlm-authentication-active-directory-on-apache-linux/

i hope be useful